# Transit through Seoul with an Indian passport from Canada

Tags: india

I have a valid temporary visa (TRV) on my Indian passport and I am travelling from Canada to India via Seoul , do I need a transit VISA?

Also I am flying back to Canada from India via Hong Kong and out of curiosity again if I would need a transit visa again for Hong Kong!

Answer (score 1):

You do not require transit visa for both directions.

Verified on https://www.traveldoc.aero

Pro Tip: HongKong offers free temporary visa, if you register online before travel. You can explore HongKong, if your transit is longer.